# Run jobs on Spark (Sinatra-Based) Java REST API?

Tags: spark-java

I want to ping another API, query and store some of the results in a database.

How should I structure this using the Spark framework?

Something like this:

[image]

#### Where Spark is the backend I've written out, client is a client pinging the endpoints of Spark I wrote out.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, does not deserve a downvote. You want to downvote me? Right a comment before you do.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks fair to me, that's how I'm starting with my new application.

Spark provides only a minimal set of features which allow for a simple lightweight specification of the REST application and let's me define the URL request handlers in a concise manner. The front end is an AngularJS powered single page application that handles all it's routing.

I found [this blog](http://www.mastertheboss.com/cool-stuff/create-a-rest-services-layer-with-spark) to be quite helpful, especially given the dearth of documentation provided by Spark itself.